# Calling multiple functions onclick of radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, click, dom-events

I am calling two functions onclick of radio buttons. It is working in Chrome but not in Firefox and IE.

```
onClick="showSelect(); showHelp();"
```

First one returns "continue" button second one returns box with information and contact number.

Comment: Is that inline HTML or an assignment in javascript?

Comment: Damn Dreamweaver. It's technically `onclick`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/webappapis.html#handler-onclick or http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#adef-onclick

Answer (score 2):

```
onClick="(function(){showSelect(); showHelp();})();";
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/neykX/)

---

**Updated**
I wrote in a comment below you want those two functions to run at the same time, meaning parallel.

Too bad... `javascript` and all modern browsers doesn't support parallel programming so I'm afraid it can't be done, but sequential, meaning one function after the other. Sorry!

Comment: Why the extra `()`? Seems like it's entirely unnecessary as the `onClick` attribute executes its function immediately anyways.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. You're wrong, I added a comment on your answer.

Comment: Ah, okay, you're right. Still, I'd like to know why your closure works and my anon. function doesn't.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville. For the very same reason [this doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/neykX/2/).

Comment: @gdoron It is not working in my case may be because i need to execute both functions at a time. But in your example it is showing one after another even i tried this as function x(){showselect(); showHelp();} and calling x still working in chrome not firefox.........

Comment: @anil. ohhh, sorry it can't be done. I'll add a full answer to the answer in a moment.

Comment: @gdoron is there any other solution you think is the best to resolve the issue? I tried a lot every change is working in chrome not in firefox.

Comment: @anil. I already told you that you can't run two function simultaneity, what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

```
onClick="(function(){showSelect(); showHelp();})()";
```

You need to wrap your `onClick` attribute in an anonymous function, and then a closure if you plan to call more than one function in it. (An anonymous function is simply a function without a name, e.g. `function(){...}`, and a closure is this: `(...)()`. It executes any code within it as soon as the compiler reaches it.)

Comment: What do you mean? mine is working fine, you can see the DEMO in my answer.

Comment: I didn't think it would. It's only instantiating the function object. You must call the function as @gdoron did.

Comment: Almost there, bro. `(...)()` is not a closure. It technically creates one while executing the script, but it is not a closure. It's simply one of the ways of calling an anonymous function.